# What is the maximum possible damage done in 1 hit?

Tags: minecraft-hypixel-skyblock

What is the most damage possible in Hypixel Skyblock, without fall damage (because this can easily get millions of damage due to the more health the mob has the more fall damage it takes). This damage must be done outside of dungeons.